# i want to display the drop down menu without hiding other data

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the  code given below when i select the 'apps' drop-down menu,it  hide the data below (ie,it's hide 'layout' and 'widjet').i need to show that data with the drop-down effect.can you help me?

```css
    #first {
        float:left;
        width:15%;
     color :bisque; 
        border-color: #023b3b;
    border-style : solid;
        height: 100%;
    background-color :#023b3b;
    }

    #boa{
        height: 5%;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;

    }

    .bob{
        text-indent: 200%;
        line-height: 210%;
        font-size: 150%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
    .boc{
        text-indent: 4%;
        color : white;
        font-size: 83%;
        font-family: sans-serif;

        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .bod{
        color:white;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        line-height: 200%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #demo {
            margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
            font-family:  sans-serif;
        }

        #demo .wrapper {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 180px;
           /* margin: 0 10px 0 0;*/
            height: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #demo .parent {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: 30px;
            height: 30px;
          /*  border-radius: 5px;*/
            background: #023b3b;
            border: 1px solid #023b3b;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #023b3b;
            color: white;
           /* font-weight: bold;*/
            z-index: 2;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-transition: border-radius .1s linear, background .1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
            -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #demo .parent:hover,
        #demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
            background: #122112;
            -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
        }

        #demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
           /* border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;*/
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #demo .content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            display: block;
            z-index: 1;
            height: 0;
            width: 180px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
            -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
            border: 1px solid #339933;
           /* border-radius: 5px;*/
            /*box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);*/
        }

        #demo .wrapper:active .content {
            height: 100px;
            z-index: 3;
            -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
        }
```

```html
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>  PROJECT </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stack.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="first" style="float:left; lngth:60%; ">
    <p><img src="image1.jpg"  id="boa"><span class="bob">First</span></p>
            <p class="boc" >Main</p>
            <div id="demo">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="parent">Dashboard</div>
        </div><br> <br>  
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Inbox</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Condact</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Calender</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Other</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">Apps</div>
        </div><br><br>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Header</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Aside</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Footer</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Other</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">Layouts</div>
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="parent">Widjet</div>
        </div>
            </div>

             <p class="boc">Componets</p>

             <p class="boc">Help</p>
             <p class="bod">&nbsp; Documents</p>

    </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

```
    #demo .content:hover {
        height: 123px;
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    }


    #demo .content ul {
        background: #339933;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;

    }

    #demo .content ul a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #demo .content li:hover {
        background: #122112;
        color: white;
    }

    #demo .content li {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #023b3b;
    }
```

In the above code when i select the 'apps' drop-down menu,it  hide the data below (ie,it's hide 'layout' and 'widjet').i need to show that data with the drop-down effect.can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you some important hints. Firstly you want to remove
`position: absolute` from `#demo .content` selector. Moreover
`position: relative;` into `position: absolute;` in `#demo .parent` selector.

This will allow whole menu to expand when it needs to fit more content.

Comment: it's working on code pen,but not in my browser know any solution

Comment: Can you give me a link to your code?
From what I remember you use some properties prefixed with webkit so ensure you have other prefixes or test in on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

add a css attribute in your UL css

```
#demo .content ul {
    background: #339933;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999; // add this in your css
}
```

Comment: i didn't get much more change...http://codepen.io/dreamhunter/pen/PzLwZY?editors=1100

Comment: i want a menu like this..http://preview.themeforest.net/item/flatkit-app-ui-kit/full_screen_preview/13231484?_ga=1.266136847.1446846814.1470679913

Comment: that shows many menu, can you confirm which one. 

I am expecting that you are trying to make http://www.agile.org.pk go to my account

Answer (score -1):

try css collapse, I think it's what you need 
[css collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

Comment: This isn't really an awnser. This is more suited for a comment.

Comment: He/She Not Having Sufficient Reputation To Use Comment Box @Kiksen